# 7zip : Set archive's LastWriteTime as old as the content

Tags: windows, powershell, zip, 7-zip

On windows, with 7za.exe v9.38, how can I set the archive's LastWriteTime (or CreationTime) same as the content?
For example : I have a "toto.txt" file, created and last written on 01/01/15.

```
7za.exe a -t7z toto.7z toto.txt
```

The "toto.7z"'s creation will be today.

With zip.exe from info-zip.org, the parameter is `-o`

> -o   make zipfile as old as latest entry

Thanks!

**EDIT** : 
You can do this with :

```
$srcDate = (Get-ChildItem $fileToCompress).LastWriteTime
$dstFile = Get-ChildItem $7zFile
$dstFile.LastWriteTime = $srcDate
```

But it would be easier with a simple command switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `-stl` switch.

7-Zip's [changelog](http://www.7-zip.org/history.txt):

> ### 9.30 alpha     2012-10-26
>
> - LZMA2 now is default compression method for .7z format.
> - 7-Zip now can update WIM archives.
> - 7-Zip File Manager now can move files to archives.
> - The default encoding for TAR format now is UTF-8. You can use -mcp=1 switch for OEM encoding.
> - Command line version:
>
>   - new "rn" command to rename files in archive.
>   - new -sdel switch to delete files after including to archive.
>   - new -sns switch to store NTFS alternate streams (for WIM format only).
>   - new -sni switch to store NT security information for files (for WIM format only).
>   - **new -stl switch to set archive timestamp from the most recently modified file.**
> - Speed optimizations for opening big archives and big disk folders.
> - 7-Zip now writes special padding blocks to headers of 7z archives for    faster archive opening. Note that 7-Zip 4.50 - 4.58 contain
>     BUG,    so these old versions can't correctly work with such new 7z
>     archives.
> - DMG support was improved
> - Some bugs were fixed.
> - The BUG in 7-Zip 9.26 alpha - 9.29 alpha versions was fixed.   These alpha versions could not open non-solid 7z archive, if    some files
>     were skipped during creation of that archive.   That problem is also
>     related to 7z archives created in solid mode,   if each solid block
>     contains no more than one file.   Note: 7-Zip skips files that were
>     open for writing by another    application and shows warning in that
>     case.
> - New localization: Aragonese.

Comment: Oh, ok, it was in changelog and not in command help... thanks, it works.